# Is there a theory of evolution that spans naturalism and humanmade systems?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, evolution

Darwin's big insight was that there are two phases that drive the evolution of species: variation and natural selection.

The term 'evolution' applies to humanmade systems, as well. E.g., the evolution of the automobile, computer, etc. These evolutions could also be describe as byproducts of a dual phase process: modification and testing. E.g., an engineer modifies a design and then tests it.

Lots of examples of dual phase evolution exist. Architecture evolves through the two phases of design/critique. Perhaps the simplest example is trial/error.

My question is this: natural selection is the theory that the evolution of species can be described by a dual phase processes. Is there a theory that all evolution can be described by two phases that are effectively modification/test?

I'm working in this area and am looking for references to this idea but every search comes back with specific examples such as natural selection. I'm looking for an arching theory that describes them all.

Comment: Dawkins understands evolution as a sieving process. There are two components: 1) some mechanism (random in nature for example) which "moves" things around or gives rise to possibilities, 2) some sieving mechanism by which things that pass the sieving criterion are selected. In the case of evolution you can think of the first mechanism as random mutations, the sieving criterion is survival through generations of genetic material. In the case of manmade phenomena the first mechanism is simply enough humans producing X, the sieving criterion is typically some performance standard for X

Comment: @FoxMulder Thanks for the thoughts. Does Dawkins also discuss his process as applying to humanmade complex systems?

Comment: I don't remember, the book where I saw this is the blind watchmaker. I do remember he discusses as an example a hole on the ground of a particular size, which eventually gets filled up with pebbles or the appropriate size to fit through the hole. I believe he links this with crystal formation, but I'd have to look at the passage again